# Is there a way to name proc rank groups based on values within the group?

Tags: sas, rank, proc

So I have multiple continuous variables that I have used `proc rank` to divide into 10 groups, ie for each observation there is now a `"GPA"` and a `"GRP_GPA"` value, ditto for Hmwrk_Hrs and GRP_Hmwrk_Hrs.  But for each of the new group columns the values are between 1 - 10.  Is there a way to change that value so that rather than 1 for instance it would be 1.2-2.8 if those were the min and max values within the group?  I know I can do it by hand using proc format or if then or case in sql but since I have something like 40 different columns that would be very time intensive.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It is not clear what you are asking.  Often, asking a question is harder than answering one.  Take a minute, try to forget everything you know about your problem, then read your question.  I'm sure we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your question if you want to store the min-max values or just format the rank columns with them.  My solution below formats the rank column and utilises the ability of SAS to create formats from a dataset.  I've obviously only used 1 variable to rank, for your data it will be a simple matter to wrap a macro around the code and run for each of your 40 or so variables.  Hope this helps.

```
/* create ranked dataset */
proc rank data=sashelp.steel groups=10 out=want;
var steel;
ranks steel_rank;
run;

/* calculate minimum and maximum values per rank */
proc summary data=want nway;
class steel_rank;
var steel;
output out=want_min_max (drop=_:) min= max= / autoname;
run;

/* create dataset with formatted values */
data steel_rank_fmt;
set want_min_max (rename=(steel_rank=start));
retain fmtname 'stl_fmt' type 'N';
label=catx('-',steel_min,steel_max);
run;

/* create format from previous dataset */
proc format cntlin=steel_rank_fmt;
run;

/* apply formatted value to rank column */
proc datasets lib=work nodetails nolist;
modify want;
format steel_rank stl_fmt10.;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Keith's good answer, you can also do the following:

```
proc rank data = sashelp.cars groups = 10 out = test;
var enginesize;
ranks es;
run;

proc sql ;
 select *, catx('-',min(enginesize), max(enginesize)) as esrange, es from test
 group by es
 order by make, model
;
quit;
```